# SQLalchemy performance when iterating queries millions of time

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a disease simulation in Python, using SQLalchemy, but I'm hitting some performance issues when running queries on a SQLite file I create earlier in the simulation.

The code is below. There are more queries in the outer for loop, but what I've posted is what slowed it down to a crawl. There are 365 days, about 76,200 mosquitos, and each mosquito makes 5 contacts per day, bringing it to about 381,000 queries per simulated day, and 27,813,000 through the entire simulation (and that's just for the mosquitos). It goes along at about 2 days / hour which, if I'm calculating correctly, is about 212 queries per second.

Do you see any issues that could be fixed that could speed things up? I've experimented with indexing the fields which are used in selection but that didn't seem to change anything. If you need to see the full code, [it's available here on GitHub](https://github.com/minorsecond/host-vector-human-model/blob/useRandomSelecotr/simulation.py). The function begins on line 399.

Thanks so much, in advance.

## Run mosquito-human interactions

```
for d in range(days_to_run):
    ... much more code before this, but it ran reasonably fast
    vectors = session.query(Vectors).yield_per(1000)  #grab each vector..
    for m in vectors:
        i = 0
        while i < biting_rate:
            pid = random.randint(1, number_humans)  # Pick a human to bite
            contact = session.query(Humans).filter(Humans.id == pid).first()  #Select the randomly-chosen human from SQLite table

            if contact:  # If the random id equals an ID in the table
                if contact.susceptible == 'True' and m.infected == 'True' and random.uniform(0, 1) < beta:  # if the human is susceptible and mosquito is infected, infect the human
                    contact.susceptible = 'False'
                    contact.exposed = 'True'

                elif contact.infected == 'True' and m.susceptible == 'True':  # otherwise, if the mosquito is susceptible and the human is infected, infect the mosquito
                    m.susceptible = 'False'
                    m.infected = 'True'
                    nInfectedVectors += 1
                    nSuscVectors += 1
                i += 1
    session.commit()
```

Comment: Would it make more sense to use session.flush() in the for loop, and then session.commit() once the loop is exited?

Comment: It would make more sense to load everything into memory and then do the simulation entirely in memory.

Comment: @univerio That was the way I tried originally, but the tables are so large (population table is ~ 2 million rows), that my computer can't handle it. I guess I could just run it on AWS.

Comment: 2m population is not that large. Taking a conservative assumption of 1 KB per `Human` object, that's only 2GB. You may want to skip the ORM in that case though; it might have significant overhead if it needs to keep track of a huge number of objects.